PCIe bus data, address and control signal misinterpretation
Have there been cases were someone changes the bits in their data to change the behavior of the controller that recieves the signals from PCIe(and I'm mentioning this because PCIe is serial, so there is theoretically a vector for attack since all signals are in 1 line)? For example imagine you have:
100101(control signals)1011010101(memory address)101011010111011(data)
And you can trick the receiving end to treat some of the data as for example part of the memory address of even treating it entirely as another request (and if I'm wrong about this please explain it to me instead of just insulting me).

PCIe is better thought of as a packet network rather than a serial bus.
Each device communicates by sending packets (data read, data write, config, interrupt, etc.) over the bus.
These packets have a predefined header and are typically generated by low level hardware controllers (as opposed to software), though a custom device (e.g. FPGA) can largely generate whatever it's programmed to.
The headers must be correctly formed elsewhere the packet should be ignored by any conformant device. This includes checksums to help weed out bit errors. You can't really confuse data for addresses because they are in different parts of the packet. Similarly you can't embed another packet in the data field because the header specifies the length of the packet (so anything in the data region is just data).
That being said, PCIe is a very low level bus in a computer system. Any device if enabled to do so is capable of reading and writing to any address of any device on the bus (peer to peer), so if you have physical access to plug in such a device, there is the potential for a device to be able to take control of a host computer.
With thunderbolt becoming commonplace, basically providing external access to the PCIe bus, a lot of work has been done to find ways to motigate some of these risks, through memory protection (IOMMU) and other device isolation techniques.
It is not perfect. Being able to install a PCIe device in a computer can provide a massive vector for attack if these mitigations are not in place without any need for trying to "trick" the bus into misinterpretating packets.

You did say checksum verification, could that be influenced by attacker input to change the final resulting value (since the PCIe packet itself is are just values)? (And yeah I am aware of DMA attacks, but I am researching for a much less intrusive form to see if it's possible, hence the question)

@HardwareNewb if you have that level of control of what is being sent, then you might as well just send a properly formed packet. If you succeed in forming a valid bitstream that somehow convinces the receiver that it has received two packets instead of one, you might as well have just sent two packets as they will be treated the same way. You couldn't do this with just controlling the data field alone because the header includes a length field.

I didn't mean the entire packet was controlled by the attacker, what I meant was that the attacker controls the data (only the data) that is being sent, so maybe he can manipulate this value so that something happens during checksum verification which leads to a change in the packet itself

@HardwareNewb then no, you can't change a packet by only controlling the data field. The header indicates the length of the data field, so no matter what you put in the data field it will only ever be treated as data.

What about this approach: since a buffer on the onboard memory can be overflown without much software countermeasures since usually it's mostly hardware, we can maybe reach into the region were the PCIe packets are getting ready? Is that a more feasible approach?

@HardwareNewb PCIe includes a flow control mechanism which means you cant send more than the receiver is able to accept. Whether there is any way to trigger an endpoint or root complex implementation to overflow the transmission buffer would be extremely hardware dependant. e.g. In an FPGA implementation I've built in the past, this wouldn't be possible as the headers aren't populated into a buffer, but rather directly sent out before the user data buffer is copied out, so overflowing that buffer could only corrupt the data content and not the headers.

I know I'm becoming a little annoying but, and I should move this to a chat, but what about exploiting the specialized processor itself? Since it takes in data and generates control signals based on it, and it's not that hardware specific (apart from having different architectures), an attacker could craft a specific data input that triggers control signals that could potentially alter the onboard memory or even the EEPROM (if it has electrical connections with the pins)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I haven't used it myself but a higher level PCILeech FPGA is reported to allow attacks such as the following by using DMA over PCIe:

PCILeech is capable of inserting a wide range of kernel implants into the targeted kernels - allowing for easy access to live ram and the file system via a "mounted drive". It is also possible to remove the logon password requirement, loading unsigned drivers, executing code and spawn system shells.

Device Security Guidance says enabling the IOMMU can mitigate such attacks by allowing PCIe DMA devices to only read or write to memory that has not been explicitly allocated (mapped) for it by the operating system.
